# How to convert Jenkins Pipeline into Multibranch Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have lots of Pipeline items in my Jenkins. I want to convert them into Multibranch Pipeline. Is it possible without deleting the Pipeline and creating a new Multibranch Pipeline? How?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your pipeline is in a Jenkinsfile, there isn't much to change.  You can assume that when the pipeline runs in a multi-branch project that the code is already (implicitly) checked out in your workspace.  The biggest difference is that you can't assume that your MBP is running on a specific branch.  It can, of course, check which branch it is running on and behave accordingly.

Comment: Yes, each project/branch has its own Jenkinsfile. But with normal Pipeline, I need to create one Pipeline per branch.

Comment: If the pipeline is on the same location, you can just create job, and align it to the jenkinsfile (path), and job will take care automatically about discovering new branches